# How to solve the resolution of second monitor on ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a monitor connected to my laptop
My laptop screen has a resolution of 1366*768 but the monitor has 1024*768
I tried this solution

```
xrandr --newmode 1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 "1368x768_60.00"
xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode "1368x768_60.00"
```

but no effect

This is an image from `xrandr` command

[image]

1. I use Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
2. My laptop Dell Inc. Inspiron N5110
3. The second monitor from Acer
4. Graphic card Intel® HD Graphics 3000

Note: The second monitor resolution works well on windows!

how can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1501095/edit) your question and add more details like what version of Ubuntu are you using?  What is the model of laptop that you are using?  What monitor model are you trying to attach to the laptop and if you know what the maximum resolution for that monitor is?  Thank you!

Comment: @Terrance Added more information

Comment: Looking at the specs of your laptop they are showing that they have a NVIDIA GT 525 in it as well.  Maybe check by running the `ubuntu-drivers` https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation and load the correct drivers.

Comment: @Terrance I followed all the instructions but the same thing

Comment: Wait, isn't the resolution supposed to be `1366x768` or `1360x768`?

Answer (score -1):

I have had good success with ARandR.

Comment: Didn't work with me